# Load excel file that changes name with SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, bids

So I have a folder in which excel files get loaded daily. I need to create a package that extract those files to a sql table. However, the file changes name daily  as the name comes with the current date,so the filename would be like filename+currentdate(name20140801.xlsx).

I tried using a variable that has filename?.xlsx/filename?*xlsx as a excelpath property for the excel connection manager but the task gives me an error DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.

Does anyone know how i can do this using the Data Flow task( I am trying to avoid Script task)

Thank you!

Comment: It's looks like something wrong in variable expression.Can you please provide your expression for excel file path variable.

Comment: ExcelFilePath is the correct property. You will need to populate that with the full file path e.g. `C:\folder\sub\name20140801.xlsx`

Comment: As I am trying to extract data from a file that changes name daily with only the last few strings(currentdate), i am trying to use  this: C:\folder\name?.xlsx, as the excelfilepath property( it works with flat tiles but it does not seem to work with excel files).

Comment: You would need a For each file loop to lookup the names of the files in the folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293882/ssis-help-archive-a-file-from-the-list-of-files-that-does-not-exist-in-sql-tabl/23302541#23302541

Comment: Thanks, I used the forearch look( file enumarator), and it works perferctly.